# How can I disable a button in polymer until a field is valid?

Tags: javascript, validation, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I like to create a basic dialog with polymer. The user shall enter a category name and if he entered something he can press on a button to save/send it. The button should be disabled as long as there is no value in the category field or as long as there is a validation error in the category field.

I tried this but it does not set the button to disabled initially.

```
<paper-input required auto-validate invalid="{{invalid}}"></paper-input>
<paper-button disabled$="[[invalid]]">Send</paper-button>

Polymer({
    is: 'list',
    properties: {  
        invalid: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        ...
```

If I use the function `validate()` on the input to compute the button value it will also trigger the invalid state (error msg) of the input although the user might not have entered something yet.

How can I get around this?

Reference: [paper-input](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/paper-input); 
[paper-button](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-button/paper-button)

[Maria's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976036/how-can-i-disable-a-button-in-polymer-until-a-field-is-valid#comment71212361_42003155) proposal with [`iron-form`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form/demo/demo/index.html):

```
<form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/" id="eventsDemo">
  <paper-input name="name" label="Name" required auto-validate></paper-input>
  <paper-button raised disabled id="eventsDemoSubmit">
</form>

<script>
  eventsDemo.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    // Validate the entire form to see if we should enable the `Submit` button.
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = !eventsDemo.validate();
  });
  document.getElementById('eventsDemo').addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = false;
  });
  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a computed binding that takes both `invalid` and the `value` as arguments.

```
<paper-button disabled$="[[isDisabled(invalid, value)]]">Enable on valid input</paper-button>
```

The isDisabled function would then check that the value has been set. For example like this:

```
isDisabled: function(invalid, value) {
    return invalid || value.length === 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it but then it is like I built my own validation. Additionally I would need to do that for each input field. If I do it like this the validation feature of the input elements do not offer "any" value.

Comment: I know it's not the most elegant solution to your problem, but I don't think there is another option

Comment: You could also wrap your button in a form component, for example [iron-form](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form/demo/demo/index.html), and install a change-listener globally for all form elements. Similar to the second to last example in the link. However, you would still need to check all values for input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGQ0h9?p=preview)

```
<paper-input  
                label="Insert number from the range [1, 10]"
                id="step"
                type="number" 
                min="1" 
                max="10"
                value="{{value}}"
                editable

                required

                auto-validate="true"
                invalid="{{invalid}}"
                preventInvalidInput
                error-message="value: {{value}}  - means invalid is {{invalid}}"

                on-change="stepChange">

</paper-input>


        <br>
        value: {{value}}
        <br>
        invalid: {{invalid}}
        <br><br><br>
        <paper-button raised disabled$="{{invalid}}">Enable on valid input</paper-button>
```

Comment: Yes but in this case it will display the error right away before the user actually did something. That is a bad user experience. This is also why the `invalid` param of `paper-input` is `false` at the `onLoad` state by default and not `true`. Forcing it to `true` via `preventInvalidInput` is not a sufficient option.

Comment: Tip: remove "required" attribute if you do not want to see validation error on load

Comment: In your updated demo you removed `required`. Now the error msg at the `onLoad` state is gone but now the button is also enabled although there is no value between 1-10. You see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure If I fully get your requirements. For sure you can try [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) and [computed properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property).
You have a nice cheat-sheet here https://meowni.ca/posts/polymer-cheatsheet/

Comment: Cheat sheet for Polymer 2.0: https://meowni.ca/posts/polymer-2-cheatsheet/